# Maybe it's python Instants variable error, TypeError: object is not iterable

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy, typeerror, iterable

```
class NameCard(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cardbook'
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(String)
    IG = Column(String, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    team = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: {self.age}, {self.IG}, {self.team}"

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    
class Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        Session = sessionmaker(engine)
        self.session = Session()
        self.getter = Getter()
        self.cards = self.session.query(NameCard)
    
    def insert(self):
        new_card = NameCard(name = self.getter.getName(), age = self.getter.getAge(), IG = self.getter.getIG(), team = self.getter.getTeam())
        self.session.add(new_card)
        self.session.commit()
            
    def listview(self):
        ## page = int(input("How many search results will you see at once?"))
        for index, card in enumerate(self.cards):
            print("index : {} :, {}".format(index,card))
            
    def modify(self):
        user = input("The IG of the person you are looking for : ")
        self.cards = self.session.query(NameCard).filter(NameCard.IG==user)
        cards_counting = self.session.query(NameCard).filter(NameCard.IG==user).count()
        if cards_counting == 0:
            print("ERROR : Not Found")
        
        else:
            for card in self.cards:
                print("Edit the information >>> ",card," <<< Edit the information ")
                m = int(input("name edit(1) age edit(2) IG edit(3) team edit(4) : "))
                
                if m == 1:
                    new = input("Enter the new name : ")
                    self.cards = self.session.query(NameCard).filter(NameCard.IG==user).one()
                    self.cards.name = new
                    new_cards = self.session.query(NameCard).filter(NameCard.IG==user)
                    
                    for new_card in new_cards:
                        print("###UPDATE Compelte >>> ",new_card)
```

When using modify() and execute listview() function, there is an error message like "TypeError: 'NameCard' object is not iterable",also program ends. But restarting the program, modifying is completed. Why this happens?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: What does mean?

Comment: Hi, the comment above means you should provide the full error message. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of the question, I think this would solve your problem.
Add .all() to the below lines

```
self.cards = self.session.query(NameCard)
self.cards = self.session.query(NameCard).filter(NameCard.IG==user)
```

ie

```
self.cards = self.session.query(NameCard).all()
self.cards = self.session.query(NameCard).filter(NameCard.IG==user).all()
```